# Segmentation Fault at algorithm update in VTK (Python)

Tags: python, vtk

I have 3 .stl files, each of which contain a cylinder that was generated from VTK (via vtkLineSource + vtkTubeFilter + vtkTriangleFilter with CappingOn). Each cylinder has different orientations, intersects at one end, and has a triangular mesh.

I want to join these three cylinders together using vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter(). I do this using the code below.

```
from vtk import *

def main():

    a = vtkSTLReader()
    a.SetFileName('booleanTest0.stl')
    b = vtkSTLReader()
    b.SetFileName('booleanTest1.stl')
    c = vtkSTLReader()
    c.SetFileName('booleanTest2.stl')

    boolOp1 = vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter()
    boolOp1.SetOperationToUnion()
    boolOp1.SetInputConnection(0,a.GetOutputPort())
    boolOp1.SetInputConnection(1,b.GetOutputPort())
    boolOp1.Update()

    boolOp2 = vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter()
    boolOp2.SetOperationToUnion()
    boolOp2.SetInputConnection(0,boolOp1.GetOutputPort())
    boolOp2.SetInputConnection(1,c.GetOutputPort())
    boolOp2.Update()

    mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(boolOp2.GetOutputPort(0))

    actor = vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    map1.SetInputConnection(a.GetOutputPort())
    map2.SetInputConnection(b.GetOutputPort())
    map3.SetInputConnection(c.GetOutputPort())

    ren = vtkRenderer()
    ren.AddActor(actor)

    renwin = vtkRenderWindow()
    renwin.AddRenderer(ren)

    iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renwin)

    renwin.Render()
    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()

main()
```

The code fails giving a segmentation fault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After some testing, I find that the first boolean passed, but the update on the second boolean causes the segmentation fault.

```
boolOp2.Update()
```

Any ideas on how to circumvent this issue? I am using Arch Linux with Python 2.7; tested with VTK 6.1.0 and 5.10.

You can download the stl's here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B27CeIphBFy-SEtLc1NPd3Z0bGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue so far? I've encountered the same problem and have no idea what's wrong

Comment: I don't quite remember if I figured it out or not, I do however remember having constant problems with repeated booleans. No matter what filters I prepped it with, there was also missing faces and other issues. I would suggest looking at this instead: [link](https://github.com/zippy84/vtkbool)